# Why is my semivariance so high?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, spatial, variogram

I am using variograms checking for spatial autocorrelation in a resiudal pattern produced by a GLMM-NB. In theory, the semivariance should be bounded between 0 and 1 (that´s what I think at least as I only see examples that have highest value of 1). However, in my variograms it´s often above 1. How can that be and what does it mean?

My Pearson residuals do not look that much skewed:

```
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 -4.753000 -0.348900 -0.046890 -0.000416  0.120400 10.720000
```

and the spatial map of the residuals is (to me) not much imbalanced. Maybe the northern part has partly higher values?

[image: Spatial Residual Map]

but the variograms behave strange! I show a short range pattern that takes only short distances into account up to 3000m with 100m interval, and a long range pattern that uses all distances up to 8000m with a 500m interval.

[image: Variograms]

Frankly, I am not sure how to interpret these, but I would say, there is no autocorrelation pattern in the residuals. If I choose different directions, it´s similar; often above 1. However, when I perform a spatial correlogram using the *ncf* package, then I get a significant short range (within 500 or 1000m) correlation.

[image: ncf correlogram]

Does anyone has any idea how to interpret these patterns? Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) What are the lag populations in those empirical variogram plots? That information is essential for interpreting them. (2) What does the `ncf` correlogram look like when plotted only for extremely small distances? (3) Since your residuals are *heavily* skewed--look at those extremes compared to quartiles!--there is no basis to suppose the semivariances will be less than $1$.

Comment: (1) I assume that the lag population is the content of the values within one lag? Then it is the residual value for a certain distance class (in meters) derived from a GLMM for overdispersed count data (tree stems). (2) if I set the lag distance to 50m then the first 250m show partly positive correlation, while the very first is significantly negatively correlated (with 0.12). (3) Hmm how do you know? Median is close to zero, 1Q and 3Q not soo far away each other. ok -4 and +10 is different but does that matter that much? ok-semivar can also be above 1, many thanks @whuber !

Comment: (3) When the extremes are so far from the middle (compared to their IQR), your semivariances will be very unstable.  (1) The lag population is, by definition, the number of distinct pairs of data contributing to the estimate for that lag.  Estimates for small lag populations are more uncertain than estimates for large ones.

Comment: (3) Ah, I see, thank you! (1) Ok, I didn´t know the definition, thank you. For the long range the number of pairs are between 75000 and 5000, smaller lags have more pairs. For the short range np are between 18K and 200, while the first 13 lags (a 50m) have always values above 10K then dropping. Maybe too many pairs so that p-values get significant too easy?